# How to see previews of old quicktime movies (old codec)

Tags: macos, quicktime, mov

Since I updated to Yosemite, the .mov previews in Finder no longer show up for videos with an older codec. (When I double click the video, it starts a conversion process.) Is there any way I can see previews of my videos without needing to convert them all? Even if there's a software I can download to see the previews, that is fine. It's too much work to convert all of the videos to see what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Finder preview function. You would have to find a preview handler written for that specific codec (whatever it might be) *and* compatible with Yosemite. A bit of searching *might* find that, if it even exists.

If all you want to do is play the video try VLC at [videolan.org](http://videolan.org) it's free and well supported and will not try and covert it, just play it as is.